# How to list the name of all AWS subnets using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-vpc

I can easily list all security group names using the following codes:

```
import boto3
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

print('All Security Groups:')
print('----------------')
sg_all = ec2_client.describe_security_groups()
for sg in sg_all['SecurityGroups'] :
    print(sg['GroupName'])
```

I am trying to list all the subnet names the same way like:

```
print('Subnets:')
print('-------')
sn_all = ec2_client.describe_subnets()
for sn in sn_all['Subnets'] :
    print(sn['SubnetName'])
```

Here, variable `sn` gets all each subnet including all properties and tags but cannot find the right property name for subnet like `GroupName`.

I can use boto3.resource('ec2') or the following codes but for simplicity I am looking for the similar method I used above to list all security groups:

```
print('Subnets:')
print('-------')
sn_all = ec2_client.describe_subnets()
for sn in sn_all['Subnets'] :
    for tag in sn['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
            print(tag['Value'])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon VPC Subnets do not have a "Name" field (whereas Security Groups *do* have a `GroupName` field).

In the management console, you can see that Security Groups have two columns: Group Name and Name. The `Name` field is actually the value of the tag called Name.

Subnets, on the other hand, only have the Name tag.

**Tip:** An easy way to see what information is available is by looking at the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) documentation for [`describe-subnets`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-subnets.html).

Comment: @ John Rotenstein - Thank you for the answer. You are correct. So, I have to use the name tag. No more choice.

Comment: Hi @Rafiq, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @ John Rotenstein - I don't know why I do not see an option to accept your answer!

Comment: @Rafiq, Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Comment: @ John - Got it. Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 7):

```
import boto3
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
print('Subnets:')
print('-------')
sn_all = ec2_client.describe_subnets()
for sn in sn_all['Subnets'] :
    print(sn['SubnetId'])
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your code, what it does and how does it answers the question.

Comment: @CosminStaicu, It will give you all the subnets of the region you are using

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I posted this question and accepted the answer from @JohnRotenstein. Learning more about AWS, boto3 and Python, I thought it would be helpful for others to give a clearer answer. I'm answering this keeping full respect to @JohnRotenstein's answer, as that explained why we cannot always just use the Subnet `Name` to list a subnet.

As the tag `Name` is optional in AWS subnets, not all subnets have this `Name` tag. So, listing the subnets based on the `Name` tag won't give all the subnets. To get all the subnets with their `Name` tags, if exists, the following solution will work. It will list all the subnets even if the `Name` tag is missing.

```
import boto3
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
print('Subnet_ID\tSubnet_Name')
print('-----------------------------')
sn_all = ec2_client.describe_subnets()

for sn in sn_all['Subnets'] :
    print(sn['SubnetId'], end='')
    for tag in sn['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
            print('\t' + tag['Value'])
```

Output:

```
Subnet_ID       Subnet_Name
-----------------------------
subnet-02d9041b12d08xxxx        public_1
subnet-085b8f0deb821xxxx        public_2
subnet-09a2ffb46dc55xxxx        public_3
```